# .htaccess force 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Attempting to restrict access to Addon Domains through the Main Domain by forcing 404 but doesn't seem to be working, here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain2.com/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain3.co.uk/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

The directory `test` is 404'd correctly, so I'm thinking it's something to do with the .com and .co.uk characters?

Comment: ¿Is this `domain3.co.uk` a folder name or a domain name?

Comment: @faa it's an addon domain through cpanel having its own folder within the main domains directory. http://domain.com/domain3.co.uk shows the same content as http://domain3.co.uk